When the unique lock is release and cv is not notified, cv still wakes up
I wrote this snippet of multithreaded code for trying to understand condition variable and mutex locks.
#include<iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;




int main() {
    mutex mtx;
    condition_variable cv;
    int counter = 0;
    // after releasing lock, what happens
    auto fn = [&] (int i) {
      {
          unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);
          cv.wait(lock, [&] {return counter % 2 == i;});
          std::cout << i << " exited wait " << std::endl;
          counter++;
      }
      std::cout << i << " Sleeping" << std::endl;
      this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
      std::cout << "Printing " << i << std::endl;
      cv.notify_all();
    };
    thread t0(fn, 0);
    thread t1(fn, 1);
    
    t0.join();
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}

I was expecting the cv.wait statement to wait until it gets the cv.notify_all(). However, the output of this program is
0 exited wait 
0 Sleeping
1 exited wait 
1 Sleeping
Printing 0
Printing 1

Which indicates the cv of thread t1 woke up even before t0 called notify_all().
At first, I thought this was because t0 releases the lock on mtx, so that implicitly wakes up cvs that is blocked with the same mutex. What confused me more was that when I comment out the cv.notify_all();, this is the output
0 exited wait 
0 Sleeping
Printing 0
** Process Stopped **

which indicates the thread t1 is stuck in cv.wait().
To summarize my question:

For the first case, why did cv in t1 wake up without being notified?
Why does this not work when cv.notify_all() is commented out even though it feels like that line of code seems to be called at the last moment in the first case.


Read about "spurious wakeups".

This is why you should ALWAYS wait for a condition variable with a predicate. Spurious wakeups do happen (it is an OS issue that cannot be resolved).

Does this answer your question? What's the correct way to deal with spurious wakeups, in general?

Adding one more line of print helped me understand the situation
0 entering wait 
0 exited wait 
0 Sleeping
1 entering wait 
1 exited wait 
1 Sleeping
Printing 0
Printing 1


** Process exited - Return Code: 0 **

It seems like t1 is blocked by mutex lock because t0 grabs the lock first. By the time t0 releases the lock, t1 skips over condition variable because the predicate returned true.
In the case where t1 grabs the lock first, it DOES enter the condition variable wait and needs the notify_all() in order to wake up.
1 entering wait 
0 entering wait 
0 exited wait 
0 Sleeping
Printing 0
1 exited wait 
1 Sleeping
Printing 1


** Process exited - Return Code: 0 **\

